# ES6 nested array destructuring soft fail

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

How to manage the soft fail of the nested arrays in ES6?

Let's say we have a nested array with items and we want to get the first item:

```js
const array = [[3,4,5,6]];
const [[firstItem]] = array; // firstItem = 3

console.log(firstItem);
```

I would like to protect against the situation when the array comes with a `null`, but apparently it doesn't work similarly to handling object soft fail:

```js
const array = [null];
const [[firstItem] = []] = array; // Uncaught TypeError: array is not iterable

console.log(firstItem);
```

Comment: i get just `undefined`, as expected ...

Comment: Same here - I only get `TypeError: array is not iterable` if I do `const [[firstItem = []]] = array` (set `firstItem` to an empty array instead of the nested array)

Comment: Sorry, I realised it doesn't work only if the first element of the array is `null`. Updated my question.

Comment: `null` prevents assignment to use its default. So it will always try to destructure `null`. I don't know if it worth to use here, but you can use Proxy to control assignment;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> **Default values**
>
> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the array is `undefined`.

You have `null` as value and not `undefined`.

```js
const array = [undefined];
const [[firstItem] = []] = array; // Uncaught TypeError: array is not iterable

console.log(firstItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can be sure, that `firstItem` is always an empty array by default (except the case you pass a `null` value):

```js
const array = [];
const [[firstItem = []] = [] ] = array;

console.log(firstItem)
```

```js
const array = [[1]];
const [[firstItem = []] = [] ] = array;

console.log(firstItem)
```